# One question on safe primes greater than $5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a safe prime greater than $5$, $t$ be an integer relatively prime to $p$, and $s$ be a positive integer.
Please simplify $f(t)$ $mod \space p$ as follow

$ f(t)=\sum_{x=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}-1} 
{((t^{2x}+1)(t^{2(x+s)}+1))^\frac{p-1}{2}+
((t^{2x}-1)(t^{2(x+s)}-1))^\frac{p-1}{2}} $,

For example, if $t≡1 (mod \space p)$ or $t≡p-1 (mod \space p)$, I can figure out $f(t)≡\frac{p-1}{2} (mod \space p)$

But then I get stuck with other situations.

Comment: A safe prime is a prime number of the form 2p + 1, where p is also a prime.